# How to append to a ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, python-3.8

I'm new to Numpy library from Python and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, could you help me please with this?

So, I initialize my ndarray like this.

```
A = np.array([])
```

And then I'm training to append into this array A a new array X which has a shape like (1000,32,32) if has any importance.

```
 np.insert(A, X)
```

The problem here is that if I'm checking the ndarray A after that it's empty, even though the ndarray X has elements inside.
Could you explain me what exactly I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: `numpy.ndarray` objects are fixed-size arrays. `.insert` and `.append` return *new array objects*.

Comment: I think you need to start with `np.concatenate`.  Practice with its examples.  Pay attention to the number of dimensions.  What's the `shape` of your `A`?  Does that have anything common with `X`?  Do not attempt to emulate `[]` and list `append`.  Why are you trying to append `X` to `A`?  Why not just use `X`?

Answer (score 3):

```
In [10]: A = np.array([])                                                                        
In [11]: A.shape                                                                                 
Out[11]: (0,)

In [13]: np.concatenate([A, np.ones((2,3))])                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
```

So one first things you need to learn about numpy arrays is that they have `shape`, and a number of dimensions.  Hopefully that error message is clear.

Concatenate with another 1d array does work:

```
In [14]: np.concatenate([A, np.arange(3)])                                                       
Out[14]: array([0., 1., 2.])
```

But that is just `np.arange(3)`.  The concatenate does nothing for us.  OK, you might imagine starting a loop like this.  But don't.  This is not efficient.

You could easily concatenate a list of arrays, as long as the dimensions obey the rules specified in the docs.  Those rules are logical, as long as you take the dimensions of the arrays seriously.

```
In [15]: X = np.ones((1000,32,32))                                                               
In [16]: np.concatenate([X,X,X], axis=1).shape                                                   
Out[16]: (1000, 96, 32)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to write back to `A` if you use `np.append`, as in `A = np.append(A,X)` -- the top-level numpy functions like `np.insert` and `np.append` are usually immutable, so even though it gives you a value back, it's your job to store it. `np.array` likes to flatten the `np.ndarray` if you use append, so honestly, I think you just want a regular `list` for A, and *that* append method *is* mutable, so no need to write it back.

```
>>> A = []
>>> X = np.ndarray((1000,32,32))
>>> A.append(X)

>>> print(A)
[array([[[1.43351171e-316, 4.32573840e-317, 4.58492919e-320, ...,
         1.14551501e-259, 6.01347002e-154, 1.39804329e-076],
        [1.39803697e-076, 1.39804328e-076, 1.39642638e-076, ...,
         1.18295070e-076, 7.06474122e-096, 6.01347002e-154],
        [1.39804328e-076, 1.39642638e-076, 1.39804065e-076, ...,
         1.05118732e-153, 6.01334510e-154, 3.24245662e-086],
...
```

Comment: It's `np.append` that flattens the inputs - if the axis is not provided.  Read the docs, or better yet, read the function's own code.  It isn't long.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/1.24/reference/generated/numpy.append.html